# Is there a way to access properties of an x-coredata:// object returned from an NSFetchRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**TL;DR: Is there a way to programmatically read/recall (NOT write!) an instance of a Core Data entity using the p-numbered "serial number" that's tacked on to the instance's x-coredata:// identifier?  Is this a good/bad idea?**

I'm using a method similar to the following to retrieve the instances of an Entity called  from a Core Data data store:

```
var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<TrackInfo> = TrackInfo.fetchRequest()
        fetchResults = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for (i, _) in Global.Vars.numberOfTrackButtons! {


        let workingTrackInfo = fetchResults.randomElement()!
        print("current track is: \(workingTrackInfo)")
```

The list of tracks comes back in fetchResults as an array, and I can select one of them at random (`fetchResults.randomElement()`).  From there, I can examine the details of that one item by coercing it to a string and displaying it in the console (the `print` statement).  I don't list the code below, but using `workingTrackInfo` I am able to see that instance, read its properties into other variables, etc.

In the console, iOS/Xcode lists the selected item as follows:

```
current track is: <MyProjectName.TrackInfo: 0x60000374c2d0> (entity:
TrackInfo; id: 0xa7dc809ab862d89d 
<x-coredata://2B5DDCDB-0F2C-4CDF-A7B9-D4C43785FDE7/TrackInfo/p22>; 
data: <fault>)
```

The line beginning with `x-coredata:` got my attention.  It's formatted like a URL, consisting of what I assume is a UUID for the specific Core Data store associated with the current build of the app (i.e. not a stable address that you could hardcode; you'd need to programmatically look up the Core Data store, similar to the functions we use for programmatically locating the Documents Folder, App Bundle, etc.)  The third item is the name of the Entity in my Core Data model -- easy enough.

But that last number is what I'm curious about.  From examining the SQLite database associated with this data store, it appears to be a sort of "instance serial number" associated with the Z_PK field in the data model.

I **AM NOT** interested in trying to circumvent Core Data's normal mechanisms to modify the contents of a managed object.  Apple is [very clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054060/10826648) about that being a bad idea.

What **I AM** interested in is whether it's possible to address a particular Core Data instance using this "serial number".**

In my application, where I'm randomly selecting one track out of what might be hundreds or even thousands of tracks, I'd be interested in, among other things, the ability to select a single track on the basis of that `p-number` serial, where I simply ask for an individual instance by generating a random `p-number`, tack it on to a x-coredata:// statement formatted like the one listed above, and loading the result (on a read-only basis!) into a variable for further use elsewhere in the app.

For testing purposes, I've tried simply hardcoding `x-coredata://2B5DDCDB-0F2C-4CDF-A7B9-D4C43785FDE7/TrackInfo/p22` as a URL, but XCode doesn't seem to like it.  Is there some other data Type (e.g. an NSManagedObject?) that allows you to set an x-coredata:// "URL" as its contents?

QUESTIONS: Has anyone done anything like this; are there any memory/threading considerations why grabbing instance names in this manner is a bad idea (I'm an iOS/Core Data noob, so I don't know what I don't know; please humor me!); what would the syntax/method for these types of statements be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close.

> x-coredata://2B5DDCDB-0F2C-4CDF-A7B9-D4C43785FDE7/TrackInfo/p22

is the `uriRepresentation()` of the [NSManagedObjectID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid) of the record.

You get this URL from an NSManagedObject with

```
let workingTrackInfo = fetchResults.randomElement()!
let objectIDURL = workingTrackInfo.objectID.uriRepresentation()
```

With this URL you can get the managed Object ID from the [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator) and the coordinator from the managed object context.
Then call `object(with:` on the context to get the object.

```
let persistentStoreCoordinator = managedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator!
if let objectID = persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: objectIDURL) {
    let object = managedContext.object(with: objectID) as! TrackInfo
    print(object)
}
```

Comment: thanks for this!  Since the goal here is to programmatically figure out how to address particular (randomly selected) instances of `TrackInfo`, how do you go about obtaining the "base" URL of the datastore (i.e. the UUID in the `uriRepresentation`)?  I was able to address a randomly selected instance by calling `.deletingPathComponent,` selecting a random number, concatenating a string into p+ rnd#, and then applying it with .appendPathComponent, but that seems very klunky.  Is there a `Filemanager.default.urls` - style way of pointing to the uriRepresentation address of the datastore?

Comment: The UUID is the identifier of the persistent store. Consider that those URLs can only be used in the scope of Core Data